# How to set Postgres path variable on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, path, windows-10

I'm on a windows machine and I am having trouble fixing this error:

I've tried to modify the path variable based on various suggestions online but nothing seems to work. I've been at this for over an hour.

I'm curious what exactly I am suppose to do to have the path variable read.

I'm on Windows 10.

I think I need idiot proof step-by-step instructions.

Here is an example of one of my attempts:

[image]

When I run **psql** from the command prompt it is not recognized.

Comment: I initially typed windows 11...I meant windows 10. Sorry. If you could please remove the down vote I would appreciate it

Comment: What exactly did you try and are you sure it's a programming problem instead of a software question?

Comment: I added a screen shot of one example. But like I said , I've been at it for over an hour

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `PATH` contains *directories*, not the actual executable.

And programs are installed in `c:\Program Files` not `c:\Windows\Program Files`.

So you need to add `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin` to the path.

Answer (score 3):

first, you have to set the path for this go to program files search for PostgreSQL folder then a folder come click on it then you will see bin folder click on there where the arrow is pointing you will get the path like this  `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13` copy it
[image]

then left-click on this PC,
Click on properties
Click on the advance system setting on your left hand side a prompt is open
then click on an environment variable
[image]

Click on the path click on edit then click on new then paste this `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13`
[image]

your environment is set then go to cmd type `psql -U Postgres` then type the password
boom done

Comment: why doesnt this get done when running the official installer?